# With the package metalogo and XeLaTeX, error occurs when typing two dots above the letter

Tags: xetex, letters

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{metalogo}

\begin{document}
\"A \"b \"U \XeLaTeX  \LaTeX
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem (tried with XeLaTex, pdflatex, latex).

Comment: I use TeXlive 2015 too, but it really happens.

Comment: @Clément I did use the XeLaTeX

Answer (score 2):

The `metalogo` package has no part in this except for the reason it loads `fontspec` when XeLaTeX is used.

The bug is in how the combining dieresis is managed by XeTeX in several fonts. When `fontspec` is loaded, the command `\"b` does `b^^^^0308` (where U+0308 is COMBINING DIAERESIS).

Example:

```
\input ifluatex.sty
\ifluatex \input luaotfload.sty \fi

\font\testA="Linux Libertine O"
\font\testB="Latin Modern Roman"
\font\testC="erewhon"
\font\testD="fbb"

\testA

A^^^^0308 b^^^^0308

\testB

A^^^^0308 b^^^^0308

\testC

A^^^^0308 b^^^^0308

\testD

A^^^^0308 b^^^^0308

\bye
```

This is the output with XeTeX:

[image]

This is the output with LuaTeX (even worse):

[image]

I'm not sure where the problem is, because the combination “b U+0308” is rendered correctly with other software:

[image]

Comment: I remember it's OK at the first time I started the TeXworks and displayed well. Is there any possibility that this problem caused by the operating system or the preferences of software?   I guessed